# Self-assigning to a column name contained in a variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column name stored in a variable. Using that variable, I want to modify the the column it refers to.

```
timestamp.column <- names(dat)[grep("time", names(dat), ignore.case = T)
```

This gives me the value "TIME_STAMP" in `timestamp.column`.
Now, I want to use this variable referencing that column and convert it to POSIXct.

```
dat[, get(timestamp.column) := as.POSIXct(get(test), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")
```

At this point, it says this:

```
Error in get(timestamp.column) : object 'START_TIME' not found
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using round brackets for  `timestamp.column` and `get` the column value

```
library(data.table)
dat[, (timestamp.column) := as.POSIXct(get(timestamp.column))]
```

---

As mentioned by @akrun, a better way is to use `.SDcols`

```
dat[, (timestamp.column) := lapply(.SD,as.POSIXct),.SDcols = timestamp.column]
```

Comment: If it is a single column you can do `.SD[[1]]`